# How to keep mobile display active in javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser

I have written a little game in javascript for mobile phones. I want to keep the screen active and prevent display sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wake-lock

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/nic79#wake-lock

please check Browser compatibility
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLock#:~:text=The%20WakeLock%20interface%20of%20the,wakelock%20property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLock#:%7E:text=The%20WakeLock%20interface%20of%20the,wakelock%20property).

Answer (score 0):

I used NoSleep.js from Rich Tibbett.

git.io/vfn01